# Multiselect returns only one option

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

im trying to get the options selected but im getting only the last selected option from the select input..

state never gets updated to multiple options..just the last option ,ive tried many  options but nothing is saving the multile options.

```
    currentPage: 3,
    custFirstname: "",
    custLastName: "",
    custPhoneNum: "",
    custEmail: "",
    vehicleNum: "",
    vehicleMake: "",
    vehicleModel: "",
    defects_tank: "",
    defects_tankLogo: "",
    defects_lightglass: "",
    defects_seatcover: "",
    defects_crashgaurd: "",
    defects_mirrors: "",
    defects_indicators: "",
    electricals_headlight: "y",
    electricals_tailLight: "y",
    electricals_console: "y",
    electricals_indicatorF: "y",
    electricals_indicatorR: "y",
    electricals_horn: "y",
    petrolLevel: "",
    battery: "",
    jobs: [],
    job: {
      description: "",
      repObserv: "",
      customerReq: "",
      typeOfService: "",
      charges: "",
      services: []
    }
  };
```

im updating the state -> job -> services

```
handleJobsDropDown = e => {
    console.log(e.target.options);
    const { options } = e.target;

    const value = [];

    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      job: { ...this.state.job, services: value }
    });
  };
```

```
  <select
              multiple={true}
              value={this.state.job.services}
              onChange={this.handleJobsDropDown}
            >
              <option value="paid">Paid Serv</option>
              <option value="free">Free Serv</option>
              <option value="chain">Chain Serv</option>
              <option value="repeat">Rpt Serv</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: It seems working https://jsfiddle.net/dhxpkL04/2/

Comment: If you are on windows try selecting multiple option by `ctrl + click` and if you are on mac try selecting multiple options by `command + click`.

Comment: omg... ctrl+click worked @NishithPatel..is this the normal behavior?..so  icant select multiple without pressing ctrl ?

Comment: thanks @NirajKaushal